# KeyError: DB00001 Using SQLite to put the data while scraping from web

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, beautifulsoup

I am using python BeautifulSoup4 to **scrape** some drugs data from the drug bank database and then to save that data in the SQLite database but it is giving me a KeyError DB00001 I am attaching the code below you can see

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("Drug.db")
cur=conn.cursor()
basic_url='https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'
event=[]
drug=pd.read_excel("drug_list.xlsx",header=None)
url_id=drug.iloc[:,0]
for i in url_id:
    soup=download(basic_url,i,num_retries=150)
    try:
        d_iden=identification(soup)
    except:
        continue
    try:
        name=d_iden['Name']
    except:
        name=''
    try:
        smile=d_iden['SMILES']
        if smile=='Not Available':
            smile=''
    except:
        smile=''
    interaction,event=interactions(i,name)

    d_attr=head_attr(soup)
    try:
        target=d_attr['Targets']
    except:
        target=''
    try:
        enzyme=d_attr['Enzymes']
    except:
        enzyme=''
    try:
        carrier=d_attr['Carriers']
    except:
        carrier=''
    try:
        transporter=d_attr['Transporters']
    except:
        transporter=''
    #Creat a table named drug first, so that you can use the insert sql code.
    cur.execute("insert into drug(id,name,interaction,smile,target,enzyme,carrier,transporter)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(drug[0][i],name,interaction,smile,target,enzyme,carrier,transporter))
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Please give us the whole traceback, or at list the entire error message and an indication of which line.  Given all your blanket try/except lines, there aren't very many places where it can come from.

Comment: Did you actually create a table called `drug`, as the comment says?

Comment: @TimRoberts: thanks for the editing. The problem seems to me to be here: `drug[0][i]`, and the OP would benefit from using `enumerate()` to get the index number of the loop to use in place of what is currently being provided to `i` which appears to be a string.

Comment: Part of that is the non-intuitive magic of `pandas`.  `drug.iloc` is going to return the contents of index column, so you should be able to use it to index into `drug`.  I think.  The traceback will help.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes I did create the drug table but also not working

Comment: @TimRoberts visit this link for whole traceback https://github.com/waqarkaleemkhan/DataAnalysis/blob/master/web_scraping_drug_bank.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is pandas indexing, which I admit I find a bit inscrutable.  I've been assuming that DB0001 was a database error, but that's not true, is it?  You could have saves us all a bit of time by mentioning that DB0001 was, in fact, the ID code for the first drug in your dataframe.  It becomes the value of `i` in `drug[0][i]`, and that's what caused the error.

You don't tell us what the name of the ID column in your dataframe is, but assuming it is "id", you want something like this:

```
drug=pd.read_excel("drug_list.xlsx",header=None)
for i in drug.index:
...
        cur.execute("insert into drug(id,name,interaction,smile,target,enzyme,carrier,transporter)values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(drug[i].id,name,interaction,smile,target,enzyme,carrier,transporter))
```

**Update**

An even easier solution just occurred to me.  In the `cur.execute` line, in your original code, you should be able to replace `drug[0][i]` with just `i`.  That is, after all, the ID for the current row.